# In post.php how can I remove onbeforeunload?

Tags: posts, javascript

I am trying to remove the onbeforeunload on post.php but none of the solution I have found online work.

I tried:

```
(function() {window.onbeforeunload null;})();
```

I am using the action: admin_footer

I also tried to put it in the header.

I tried a few other things but to no avail.

On the post.php I removed the wysiwyg.

I am using WordPress version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used this code:

```
$(".button").mousedown(function(){$(window).unbind();});
```